# How to remove the hash from the URL of an Angular app that has only one route, so ui.router is unnecessary?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*This question has been [previously asked but remains **unanswered**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227509/angularjs-call-one-route-without-the-hash), with no comments.*

I have an Angular app that has a single route. I'd like to remove the `#` from the URL for my app.

If the app had multiple routes I would use `html5Mode` with `ui.router`. Since it has just the one route uiRouter is unnecessary, and I'd rather not add the bloat of uiRouter to my app simply to remove the `#`.

For example: My URL currently appears as `www.myapp.com/#?name=johnsmith`. I would like it to appear as `www.myapp.com/?name=johnsmith`.

Comment: probably it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Comment: @The That's it! If you post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the *$locationProvider* and set *html5Mode* to *true*

```
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when(/someurl);
        ...
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // removing hashtag from url
     }
)
```

As i've already wrote you can find a bit more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Thanks